# Strong and weak control

Tags: error

I have been searching for some explanations of weak and strong control for errors, but I do not really understand what it means.

Could someone help me?

Strong control refers to the control of Type I error rate under any combination of true and false null hypotheses and weak control refers to the case when all null hypotheses are true, i.e., under a null hypothesis satisfying the complete null hypothesis, but... how do we know that all null hypothesis are true? In a control experiment? So should one use weak control only for "control experiments"?

Thanks in advance